# the menu and alacarte - I'm missing something. Ubuntu 20.10 GNOME desktop (to the best of my knowledge)

Tags: menu, 20.10, alacarte

Just because I would like a menu and I have a few RasPi's and they have that nice drop down menu.

I thought it was all encompassed by `alacarte`, but it isn't.   `alacarte` is only the menu editor.

But **which** menu?

I want to get the menu working, but obviously running `alacarte` only opens the editor.

Not the actual menu, which I want.

Comment: Sorry....
I'm using Ubuntu 20.1 and GNOME desktop to the best of my knowledge.

Comment: What can I say......   The Ubuntu says it is Ubunty 20.1file:///home/me/Pictures/Screenshot%20from%202020-11-03%2020-34-07.png
Ok, that didn't work it seems.
Try this:   https://anonfiles.com/D6Y4q7m8p3/Screenshot_from_2020-11-03_20-34-07_png
Do I really need to add TRAILING 0's?

Comment: The picture states Ubuntu 20.10, meaning the 2020-October release of Ubuntu (note it says 10 not 1; it is not a decimal .10, but 10 representing October as the month; releases are *year.month* in format).  It's best if you edit your question & add release details to your question (more people read questions rather than comments)

Comment: I am really stumbling in this forum how to do things.
I will try to edit the topic.
Ok, I give up.  How do I edit the topic/subject (what ever it is called here)
Done.  Just so it is declared.